# How to call JSF backing bean method only when onclick/oncomplete/on... event occurs and not on page load

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, onclick

I have two image buttons:

```
<div class="sidebarOptions">
    <input type="image" src="images/homeButton.jpg" onclick="#{home.setRendered(1)}"/>
</div>
<div class="sidebarOptions">
    <input type="image" src="images/memberButton.jpg" onclick="#{home.setRendered(2)}"/>
</div>
```

However, the both methods are immediately invoked when the page loads with values 1 and 2. Also when I click it, the both methods are invoked.

How can I achieve the desired functionality of only calling the bean method when the image button is actually clicked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This approach will not work. You seem to be confusing/mixing the basic web development concepts of the "server side" and "client side" and to be misunderstanding the role of JSF and EL.

JSF is a server side language which runs on the webserver upon a HTTP request and produces HTML/CSS/JS code which get returned with the HTTP response. All EL expressions in form of `${}` and `#{}` will be executed in the server side during generating the HTML output. JavaScript is a client side language which runs on the webbrowser and works on the HTML DOM tree. The HTML onclick attribute should specify a JavaScript function which will be executed in the client side on the particular HTML DOM event.

In order to invoke a JSF managed bean method, you need the `action` or `*listener` attribute. JSF provides components to generate the desired HTML and specify the desired ajax actions which would change the server side state. An `<input type="image">` can be generated using a `<h:commandButton image>`. A bean method can be invoked by the `action` attribute of that component. That component can be ajaxified by embedding the `<f:ajax>` tag.

So, the following should do it for you:

```html
<h:form>
  <div class="sidebarOptions">
    <h:commandButton image="images/homeButton.jpg" action="#{home.setRendered(1)}">
      <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":sidebar" />
    </h:commandButton>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebarOptions">
    <h:commandButton image="images/memberButton.jpg" action="#{home.setRendered(2)}">
      <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":sidebar" />
    </h:commandButton>
  </div>
</h:form>

<!-- The below is just a guess of what you're really trying to achieve. -->
<h:panelGroup id="sidebar" layout="block">
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{home.rendered eq 1}">
    Home
  </h:panelGroup>
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{home.rendered eq 2}">
    Member
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)
- [How to invoke a managed bean action method in on* attribute of a JSF component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096643/how-to-invoke-a-managed-bean-action-method-in-on-attribute-of-a-jsf-component)
- [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript)

Comment: i get the same issue but in my case i want to set a variable by passing my dataTable row index so here's the code:     `<p:commandLink id="deleteExecutionResBtn" 
              onclick="deleteConfirmation.show();" action="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.setExecutionResindex(#{rowIndex})" style="margin-right:5px" title="delete an Execution Result">
             <h:graphicImage
              value="../images/cssImg/sub_blue_delete.png" heigth="30"
              width="35" />
             
            </p:commandLink>`                   but i'm getting:Failed to parse the expression

Comment: @AmiraGL: this problem is unrelated. Remove the inner `#{` and `}`. This is invalid.

Comment: It was a little jump to conclusion by assuming that 'misunderstanding the role of JSF and EL'. I was looking into this solution as I know that onclick would not invoke the the whole jsf lifecycle, and I could simply make an ajax call without validation. I could potentially call an out of order ajax call directly using javascript ... However reading in between the lines it seems to be I might be able to do with a listener.