# How to invoke a managed bean action method in on* attribute of a JSF component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, action, managed-bean

I'd like to invoke a managed bean action method in an `on*` attribute. In my particular case I need to logout an user if the user is idle for 3 minutes as below:

```
<p:idleMonitor onidle="#{mybean.processTimeOut()}" timeout="180000" />
```

However, the managed bean action method is immediately invoked as the page loads. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Redirect user to a specific page after 3 minutes? Invalide his session and show a custom message? "logs out the user immediately lands in the main page" is not very clear to me, could you clarify?

Comment: @Mathieu Castets yes I want to redirect the user to login page if he is idle for 3 minutes. The code have provided its in mainDashboard but it logs out the user to login page immedialy it initialize to mainDashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like as all other `on*` attributes on all JSF components, [the `onidle` attribute must represent a JavaScript callback](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/5.0/core/primefaces-p/idleMonitor.html), not a JSF backing bean action method. Any EL expressions in `on*` attributes would be evaluated immediately as `String` value expressions during generating the HTML output in expectation that they print (part of) JavaScript code.

It's exactly like as if you're doing `<h:outputText value="#{mybean.processTimeout()}">`. If you had removed the parentheses `()`, you'd have faced a `PropertyNotFoundException` which was also a hint at its own of it being evaluated as a value expression instead of a method expression.

In order to invoke a JSF backing bean method using JavaScript, you need an additional [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml).

```
<p:idleMonitor onidle="processTimeout()" timeout="180000" /> 
<p:remoteCommand name="processTimeout" action="#{mybean.processTimeOut}" />
```

If you're not on PrimeFaces, head to the alternatives posted in this related answer: [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript/16588912#16588912)

Comment: @BalusCafter trying your example this is the "error am getting XML Parsing Error: no element found"

Comment: I have seen my problem I had not included <h:form> between the two tags thanks alot