# How can I update the inputText in p:ajax onsuccess

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my example, the bean `paisMB` opens a dialog with a datatable for the user search a object. In the bean `portoMB` I have the controller of a crud that uses the object searched in the `paisMB`.

The code below works, but it does not update the inputText, the `update` of the `<p:ajax>` execute before the `onsuccess`. **How can I update the inputText?**

```
<p:inputText id="pais" label="País" value="#{paisMB.paisSelecionado.nome}" required="true" readonly="true" />
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-search" actionListener="#{paisMB.openPaisDialog}" >
    <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" update="panel" 
        listener="#{paisMB.onPaisChosenFromDialog}"
        onerror="#{portoMB.portoSelecionado.setPais(null)}"
        onsuccess="#{portoMB.portoSelecionado.setPais(paisMB.paisSelecionado)}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate to your technical problem, but not to your concrete requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29096643 Is it in any case helpful?

Answer (score 0):

[BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) showed me an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096643/how-to-invoke-a-managed-bean-action-method-in-on-attribute-of-a-jsf-component) that fixes my problem.

The following is the modified code:

```
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-search" actionListener="#{paisMB.openPaisDialog}" >
    <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{paisMB.onPaisChosenFromDialog}"
        onerror="setPaisNull()" onsuccess="setPaisObj()" />
    <p:remoteCommand name="setPaisObj" update="panel" action="#{portoMB.portoSelecionado.setPais(paisMB.paisSelecionado)}" />
    <p:remoteCommand name="setPaisNull" update="panel" action="#{portoMB.portoSelecionado.setPais(null)}" />
</p:commandButton>
```