# p:ajax oncomplete method is called automatically

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using p:ajax in a primefaces slider and treenode. whenever I expand the tree, the oncomplete method is always called automatically. Can anyone tell me how to stop this automatic call

---

```html
<p:tree value="#{Bean.root}" var="node" dynamic="true">
 <p:ajax event="expand"  
  oncomplete="PF('primefacesPersoDialog').initPosition()" /> 
  <p:treeNode> 
   <p:outputPanel rendered="#{something ..}">
    <div style="styling ..">
     <h:outputText style="styling .."
       value="#{node.name }" />
        <p:outputPanel style="styling ..">
         <h:inputHidden id="aaa"
          value="#{node.selection}" />
         <p:slider for="aaa" step="1" maxValue="2"  style="styling .." > 
          <p:ajax event="slideEnd"  
           listener="#{bean.methodOne}" 
           oncomplete="#{bean.methodTwo(node)}" 
           update="@this" process="@this" />
         </p:slider> 
        </p:outputPanel>
       </div>
      </p:outputPanel>
      </p:treeNode>
      </p:tree>
```

Comment: So doing a comparable thing in an `f:ajax` in a `h:commandButton`  works?

Comment: even f:ajax didn't work for me

Comment: See, it is not PrimeFaces related... Not even ajax (same would happen doing an `onclick` on a commandButton in plain jsf without ajax). So it is not javascript related either...

Comment: This is the 'better' duplicate btw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096643/how-to-invoke-a-managed-bean-action-method-in-on-attribute-of-a-jsf-component and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705614/how-to-call-jsf-backing-bean-method-only-when-onclick-oncomplete-on-event-occ

Comment: guys this is not a duplicate, I've already checked all the answers you mentioned and even much more and i did not find any solution

Comment: Sorry, you are plain out wrong, 100000%... it IS a duplicate. You **CANNOT** add a EL reference to a Java server side method in the oncomplete.... Just is not how it works....

Comment: And the **java** method in `oncomplete="#{bean.methodTwo(node)}"` (javascript has functions) is called when the node is expanded is because you have `dynamic="true"` on the tree. If you remove that, it will be called (multiple times, once for each node) And if you checked all posts and did not notice the oncomplete is wrong that is remarkable.

Comment: if you have `<p:ajax event="expand"    oncomplete="PF('primefacesPersoDialog').initPosition()" />` Primefaces will call `initPosition()`after every expand of your tree. That's what you wanted.

Comment: @Holger I'm not talking about that oncomplete, it's the other one (oncomplete="#{bean.methodTwo(node)}" ) that is always automatically called

Comment: @Omar But not from oncomplete. Oncomplete is a javascript call. Your `bean.methodTwo(node)` may be called when the slider is rendered, but never ever if oncomplete is activated after the ajax call of the slider.